# When I post info from one page to another in php nothing happens

Tags: php, html, authentication, system, profile

I am making a log in system using php. The login and signup itself works, but what I have is so after logging in, the page uses php to print a html form with the hidden inputs for the username and password, and the submit button posts those inputs to the 'profile' php page, which displays messages from that user, and allows the user to post a new message.
Login.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
    $canconnect=false;
    $user_name="root";
    $password="";
    $database="users";
    $server="localhost";
    $user=$_POST['username'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $db_handle=mysql_connect($server,$user_name,$password);
    $db_found=mysql_select_db($database,$db_handle);
    if($db_found){
        $SQL="SELECT * FROM users";
        $result=mysql_query($SQL);
        while($db_field=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            if(($user==$db_field['Username'])&&($pass==$db_field['Password'])){
                $canconnect=true;
            }
        }
        mysql_close($db_handle);
        if($canconnect){
            print("Welcome, ".$user."<br><form name='ftoprof' method='post' action='profile.php'><input type='hidden' name='hiduser' value='<?php echo $user;?>'/><input type='hidden' name='hidpass' value='<?php echo $pass;?>'/><input type='submit' name='profsub' value='View Profile'/></form>");
        }else{
            print("Username or password incorrect, please try again.");
        }
    }else{
        print("Users Database not found.");
        mysql_close($db_handle);
    }
}else{
    print("Enter Username and corresponding Password.");
}
?>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="login.php">
<input type="text" name="username" value="User"/>
<input type="text" name="pass" value="password"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit"/>
</form>
Don't have an account? <a href="signup.php">Sing Up</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know if the problem is here or on the profile.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Profile</title>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['profsub'])){
$user=$_POST['hiduser'];
$pass=$_POST['hidpass'];
$canconnect=false;
$username="root";
$password="";
$server="localhost";
$database="users";
$db_handle=mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);
$db_found=mysql_select_db($database,$db_handle);
if($db_found){
    $SQL="SELECT * FROM users";
    $result=mysql_query($SQL);
    while($db_field=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if(($user==$db_field['Username'])&&($pass==$db_field['Password'])){
        $canconnect=true;
    }
    }
    $SQL="SELECT * FROM messages";
    $result=mysql_query($SQL);
    while($db_field=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    print($db_field['message']."<br><br>");
    }if($canconnect){
    print("<form name='mesform' method='post' action='profile.php'><input type='hidden' name='user' value='<?php echo $user; ?>'/><input type='text' name='message' value='message'/><input type='submit' name='messub' value='submit'/></form>");
    }
}else{
    print("Database not found");
}
}elseif(isset($_POST['messub'])){
$mes=$_POST['message'];
$user=$_POST['user'];
$server="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="users";
$db_handle=mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);
$db_found=mysql_select_db($database,$db_handle);
if($db_found){
        $SQL="INSERT INTO messages (User, Message) VALUES ('{$user}','{$mes}')";
        $result=mysql_query($SQL);
    }else{
        print("Database not found");
    }

}else{
print("No user's profile to display");
}
?>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I input the username and password in the login page and it brings up a button saying 'view profile'. The users database table has Username Password Email and Power(admin). The Messages db table just has Message and User(that posted it).
When I click on the 'view profile' button, it brings me to the profile page, but NOTHING at all shows up on that page, I can't tell what the problem is, I can't tell of any situation that would result in this. Please tell me what I need to do to my code to make this work. By the way, I'm running a 'server' with wamp on my computer, hence I used localhost. This is my first php project so I didn't expect to be perfect on my first try without any help, and yes I realize the password uses text I'll change that if I get it to work(input type="password" right?)
Thanksin advance

Comment: Say it with me, "PDO, PDO, PDO, PDO"  Please look at using PDO - all other methods of database access in PHP are old and should not be used.  Use parameterized queries too.  also, you should hash (with a salt) your passwords.

Answer (score 2):

```
print("Welcome, $user <br><form name='ftoprof' method='post' action='profile.php'><input type='hidden' name='hiduser' value='$user'/><input type='hidden' name='hidpass' value='$pass'/><input type='submit' name='profsub' value='View Profile'/></form>");
```

replace the line after

```
if($canconnect){
```

with line above that will probably fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

Please! For the love of security don't use this code!

As @TimG said in the comments "PDO, PDO, PDO"

Just to help education you, let me mention two MAJOR issues this code has:

**ISSUE1**

This select statement asks for ALL users, then cycles through them.  Database queries should use a `WHERE` clause to limit the amount of data it moves around.

```
$SQL="SELECT * FROM users";
while($db_field=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  if(($user==$db_field['Username'])&&($pass==$db_field['Password'])){
      $canconnect=true;
  }
}
```

**ISSUE2** The real killer:

```
$SQL="INSERT INTO messages (User, Message) VALUES ('{$user}','{$mes}')";
```

This is an SQL-injection attack waiting to happen.  You can google more on that term, but in short -- SQL injection attacks are one of the most common, easiest and dangerous vulnerabilities out there.  This code, literally, is an open door to the rest of the database.

**ISSUE 3** Plain text passwords

Storing passwords in plain text is a very bad idea.  There are a number of discussions here on SO over about how to salt and encrypt passwords.

If you are going to learn Database programming in PHP, spare yourself the heart ache of learning crap and learn PDO and security from the get-go.

Comment: Also, do a little reading on salting and hashing passwords with one-way encryption. One-way encryption is a tricky concept to get at first, but really important for keeping your users info secure - especially since most users will continue to use the same password for everything.